# Taxes when remote working for a Swiss company whilst living in the UK?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, self-employment, working-abroad, switzerland

In the scenario where I'm living in the UK and working remotely for a Swiss company. Who should I pay income tax to?

I would be declared self employed in the UK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To HMRC. You pay tax in your tax *domicile* (i.e. where you more or less permanently reside) – in this case, the UK.

Rules are, of course, a little more nuanced than that. For example, if you don't bring the money back into the UK at all (e.g. if you get paid by your Swiss employer into a Swiss bank account), the situation may change.

The guidelines for whether your foreign income doesn’t need to be subject to UK tax are here:

https://www.gov.uk/tax-foreign-income/non-domiciled-residents